# F keys on a PXE boot (Dell Latitude 830)

Tags: pxe

So i just got in a shipment of Dell D830s, and im trying to do a PXE boot to our WDS servers....but when I get past the boot option screen to the pre PXE screen that asks for "Press F-12 for network boot"...my F keys appear to be disabled. This is strange because I use f-12 to get to the boot options menu. I've messed with every Bios option I can think to, and Google has only turned up changing my WDS config, which i would rather avoid as it works with every other model.

Answer (score 1):

Is there an f-lock key?  I've come across this on media centre type keyboards but not on anything else.

Comment: This particular model is a laptop, and I dont see any F key toggles.

Comment: I would have suggested maybe the fn key was stuck but from context I'm guessing you've tried more than one of the laptops

Comment: Yessir. They have been disk killed and shipped from a sister office as well. I've also confirmed that the WDS is active and functioning. Usually there is a Bios setting for F key behavior on boot...but in this case all I can find is Fn options. I also tried spamming different variations of the Fn key, ctrl, alt and with num lock on and off...just on the off chance lol.

Comment: Have you made sure your network card is set to on with PXE in the bios some Dell documentation seems to suggest the default is on without PXE

Comment: PXE picks up the DHCP and registers the IP and is ready to boot to the PE environment...but I can't confirm the network boot because f-12 wont register as a keystroke.

Comment: OK, last idea.  Do you have a USB keyboard available to try?

Comment: I have tried an external USB keyboard and the same issue arises.

Comment: Does the key work if you boot to a LiveCD or something like that?

Comment: I can use f12 to get into the boot options menu, so the key itself is functioning.

Answer (score 0):

Recent Dell computers have a BIOS setting that swaps the default position of the Fn key. Try using <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd> or going to the BIOS and toggling that setting.

I know you said it can't be this because you can use the key to get boot options, but I'm not convinced: the boot options may be looking for either F12 or the Fn version.